# Regex c# abbreviation with repetition

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to test if the text I enter is an abbreviation, assuming all abbreviations are capital letters and have a full stop after each letter.

I'm currently using:

```
Regex.IsMatch(textBox4.Text, "([[A-Z].)+"
```

but it only works for the first capital letter and full stop.

Comment: dot in regex matches any character.  I think it should be escaped:  `([[A-Z]\.)+` not sure if this is full solution to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dot in a regular expression matches any character. If you want to match a dot you must scape it with a backslash `\`.

So, the regular expression you are searching for should be:

```
([A-Z]\.)+
```

Comment: if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox4.Text, "([A-Z]\.)+")) i get an error unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: Use @"([A-Z]\.)+". The @ makes it a raw string literal. Normal string literals have special characters that are things like \n for new line and \t for horizontal tab.

Comment: c# uses `\` as an escape character. either escape it as `\\` or prefix the string with @ to have c# ignore escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what your regex code should look like (you needed to escape your ".").

```
        Regex r = new Regex(@"([A-Z]\.)+");
        Match m = r.Match("A.B."); // this works
        m = r.Match("AB");  // this one will fail
        m = r.Match("X.Y.Z."); // this works
```